# Is there any way to "lift" a constructor?

Tags: haskell, constructor, monads, option-type, lifting

Assume I have a function (`plusOne` in the example below) that only accepts and returns an `Int`. But I don't have an `Int`; instead, I have a `Maybe Int`; and if this `Maybe Int` contains a value then I want to pass it to `plusOne` and get a `Just` of whatever `plusOne` returns, or if its rather a `Nothing` then I want this `Nothing` to propagate.

In such a case we have `liftM` to code this in an elegant way:

```
import Control.Monad

plusOne :: Int -> Int
plusOne n =
    n+1 -- a very complicated computation that is failsafe

main =
    let n = Just 15 -- a very complicated computation that can fail
    in let res = liftM plusOne n
    in print res
```

So far so good. But, can something like this be done with constructors as well?

Forget about `plusOne`. Now I have: `data SomeData = SomeData Int` and want to obtain a `Maybe (SomeData Int)` from my `Maybe Int`. The solution seems noticeably less elegant:

```
import Control.Monad

data SomeData = SomeData Int
    deriving Show -- so that print works

main =
    let n = Just 15
    in let res = n >>= (\nn -> Just (SomeData nn))
    -- alternatively: in let res = liftM (\nn -> SomeData nn) n
    in print res
```

Both solutions above (with `>>=` or with `liftM`) require going through an anonymous lambda function which, to my intuition, shouldn't be necessary and only serves to clobber the code. Is there a way to avoid it? Can I somehow "lift" the `someData` constructor just as I could lift `plusOne` in the first snippet?

Comment: `\nn -> Just (SomeData nn)` is just `Just . SomeData`.

Comment: `let res = liftM (\nn -> SomeData nn)` is identical to `liftM SomeData`. (Or indeed to `fmap SomeData` - it's personal choice but I prefer calling the function `fmap`.)

Comment: can't edit now, but I obviously meant "is identical to `let res = liftM SomeData`" in the above

Comment: @RobinZigmond Wow, thank you! Didn't know constructors count as functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use function composition:

```
main =
    let n = Just 15
        res = n >>= Just . SomeData
    in print res
```

although as Robin Zigmond points out, you can simply use `fmap`, since `fmap f x` is equivalent to `x >>= return . f`, and `return == Just` for the `Maybe` monad.

```
main = let n = Just 15
           res = fmap SomeData n  -- or SomeData <$> n
       in print res
```

Moral of the story: don't use a monad where all you need is a functor.

Comment: So now you prompted me to check what the hay `fmap` is :) Dang I know and understand very few about Haskell and yet the esteemed Academy wants me to do quite a large homework involving monads after no more than two months of introduction to this language.

Comment: I also don't know what functors are ;P even though this was skimmed over during one of the lectures, too bad I didn't pay too much attention. I'm just starting to understand the very basics of monads, that's where I am.

Comment: Either you aren't paying attention in class, or your class is doing things *extremely* backwards. You should have learned functors *long* before being introduced to monads (since every monad *is* a functor, both by mathematical definition and in Haskell, since a `Functor` instance is required for every type defining a `Monad` instance).

Comment: Perhaps both. Please, there's *half a semester* for Haskell. I feel this is too short of a time. I feel kind of overwhelmed by lots and lots of new concepts introduced in a very short time.

Comment: totally agree with @chepner that the way you seem to be learning is backwards. If you need a relatively quick and pain-free introduction to these concepts, I would strongly recommend [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) - especially in this context chapters 11 and 12.

Comment: @gaazkam `fmap` and `liftM` are exactly the same, except that `fmap` works on a (very) few more types than `liftM` does.

Comment: @gaazkam I agree with you on a half semester being too short. Learning functional programming, especially with algebraic types, polymorphism, typeclasses, functors, monads, etc. requires more time.